# Several EditTexts focused in Listview once is clicked

Tags: android, android-listview

I have listview that holds a textview and editText as row entries. Once the list has been built a user can click on a specific editText and provide a value and scroll to another and do the same. This is being achieved as desired with no repeating of data in editText entries. However when I click on an edittext I find others have also been focused below.I have the code for my custom adapter below: I have also added android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" for the host activity

```
 public class StockWatch_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

 private Activity activity;
 private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

 public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> filteredData;
 private String [] arrTemp;


  public StockWatch_Adapter (Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) 
 {
activity = a;
inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
filteredData = d;
arrTemp = new String [filteredData !=null ? filteredData.size() : 0];
}

public int getCount() 
{
return filteredData !=null ? filteredData.size() : 0;
}
public Object getItem(int position) 
{
return filteredData.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) 
{
return position;
}
public static class ViewHolder {
   TextView sku;
   EditText sku_quantity;
   int ref;
}

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
 {
 final ViewHolder holder;
 View vi = convertView;
 if(convertView==null){
   vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_cocacola__listrow, parent, false);

 holder = new ViewHolder(); 
 holder.sku = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lbl_sku);
 holder.sku_quantity = (EditText)vi.findViewById(R.id.edtxt_quantity); 
 vi.setTag(holder);
 }
 else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
 }

 HashMap<String, String> accounts = new HashMap<String, String>();
 accounts = filteredData.get(position);

 holder.ref=position;  
 holder.sku.setText( accounts.get(StockWatch_OpeningStock.KEY_SKU));
 holder.sku_quantity.setText(arrTemp[position]);
 holder.sku_quantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence args,int arg1,int ar2,int arg3){

   }

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence args,int arg1,int ar2,int arg3){

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged (Editable arg0){
    arrTemp[holder.ref]=arg0.toString();
}
});
return vi;

}

 }
```

Comment: Did you try adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in your layout?

Comment: In the edittext entry in the layout?

Comment: No..just add it the LinearLayout or RelativeLayout or within whatever your edittext is...

Comment: If I do that then all the edittexts cannot be clicked

Comment: You should be able to click them individually.

Comment: Nope....thats not the case

Comment: Setting your listview to `setItemsCanFocus(true);` and listview layout with `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` did not work  for you?

Comment: The list behaves wrongly also. Still not working as desired